# Addresses with or without /index.html have different behaviors

Tags: html, nginx

I have this in my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name t.example.net;
    include ssl.conf;
    location / {
        return 403;
    }
    location ~ ^/(\w+) {
        return 403;
        location ~ ^/(\w+)$ {
            root /data/t/$1;
            try_files /index.html =404;
        }
        location ~ ^/(\w+)/(.*)$ {
            root /data/t/$1;
            try_files $2 =404;
        }
    }
    include favicon.conf;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/t.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/t.error.log;

}
```

In `/data/t/lipsum/index.html`, there is a image, which is located in `/data/t/lipsum/bender.jpg`:

```html
<img src="bender.jpg" alt="Bender">
```

When visited from `https://t.example.net/lipsum/index.html`, the picture is fine, but it breaks when visited from `https://t.example.net/lipsum`.

If I change the `img` tag to `src="lipsum/bender.jpg"`, the behavior is reversed: `https://t.example.net/lipsum` is fine and `https://t.example.net/lipsum/index.html` breaks.

How can I let them both work, or keep people from visiting `/index.html`?

Comment: Why do not use a full path `src="/lipsum/bender.jpg"`?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the configuration below on my server, which correctly maps the following URLs:

```
https://t.example.net/             # 403 forbidden
https://t.example.net/index.html   # 403 forbidden

https://t.example.net/lipsum       # /data/t/lipsum/index.html
https://t.example.net/lipsum/      # /data/t/lipsum/index.html
https://t.example.net/lipsum/foo   # /data/t/lipsum/foo/index.html
```

```
server {
  ...

  # forbid root URI
  location ~ ^/(index.html)?$ {
    return 403;
  }

  # require first URI part: /$1
  # optionally match everything after: /$1$2
  location ~ ^/([^/]+)(.*)? {
    root /data/t/$1;
    try_files $2 $2/index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would the down-voter be willing to explain why this didn't work?  Fully-tested and working on my end.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this showed up in the Low Quality queue. Is it possible someone downvoted this because it's just a code dump with no explanation?

Comment: Thanks @SiKing. I added some source/destination mapping info.